# HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error 0x8007000d

Tags: .net, iis

I refreshed my window. After that when I installed IIS and run my authorization server the error appeared.
I have gone through many solutions of this error but none fixed my problem. I have installed Rewrite Module 2 as well.

Kindly help me out if you know the solution.
[Screenshot of my authorization server when I run it on IIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkNQP.png)

[Screenshot of my web.config file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFqaG.png)

[Screenshot of Error BY JexusManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49DTw.png)

Comment: https://www.jexusmanager.com/en/latest/tutorials/oob-500.html Cleary you did not install ANCM, and Jexus Manager would show you the link.

Comment: Thanks Lex Li. I installed JexusManger and run my site on this. but it shows me this error (i updated the question with this error screenshot). do you know how to resolve this?

Comment: http://www.bitshop.com/Blogs/tabid/95/EntryId/109/IIS-8-0-Detailed-Error-500-19-Internal-Server-Error.aspx Have you unlocked the `handlers` section? If you don't, do that now.

Comment: Lex Li. I Have followed the same tutorial as well. but still its not working